# Compute hash-value of entered value when insert or update using sql server 2008 by triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with two columns {FlatContent, HashedContent}. Now I want to automatically compute the hash value of FlatContent when new row was inserted or an existing row was updated. To date, I've never used from trigger, so I can't do this by trigger or another approach which is exist to solve this issue.

Thanks if anybody can help me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a trigger, make HashedContent a [persisted computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) in your table definition.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD HashedContent AS HashBytes('SHA1', FlatContent) PERSISTED
```

Comment: Thanks but i think i can't use this feature because i'm use of varbinary data-type and i can't turn IsPersisted option on!

Comment: @Sadegh: You could still create the computed column without the PERSISTED option. You just wouldn't be able to index it.

Comment: Now I'm going to do this. Thanks Joe ;)